# ACF options add submenu with a callback function

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I want to add a custom submenu to option page so that I can render page with callback function I add.  If I create acf_add_options_sub_page I must use the acf field to generate the options page.

```
if( function_exists('acf_add_options_page') ) {
    
    acf_add_options_page(array(
        'page_title'    => 'Theme General Settings',
        'menu_title'    => 'Theme Settings',
        'menu_slug'     => 'theme-general-settings',
        'capability'    => 'edit_posts',
        'redirect'      => false
    ));
    
    acf_add_options_sub_page(array(
        'page_title'    => 'Theme Header Settings',
        'menu_title'    => 'Header',
        'parent_slug'   => 'theme-general-settings',
    ));
    
    acf_add_options_sub_page(array(
        'page_title'    => 'Theme Footer Settings',
        'menu_title'    => 'Footer',
        'parent_slug'   => 'theme-general-settings',
    ));
    
}
```

---

### What i tried

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'main_home' );

/**
 * Adds a submenu page under a custom post type parent.
 */
function main_home() {
    add_submenu_page(
        'theme-general-settings',
        __( 'Books Shortcode Reference', 'textdomain' ),
        __( 'Shortcode Reference', 'textdomain' ),
        'manage_options',
        'books-shortcode-ref',
        'books_ref_page_callback'
    );
}
 
/**
 * Display callback for the submenu page.
 */
function books_ref_page_callback() { 
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h1><?php _e( 'Books Shortcode Reference', 'textdomain' ); ?></h1>
        <p><?php _e( 'Helpful stuff here', 'textdomain' ); ?></p>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

Result
It does not work :  url becomes like :  website.com/wp-admin/books-shortcode-ref

If I change books-shortcode-ref to theme-general-settings it works but the it becomes same as what acf plugin used to go.. I have to add options using acf fields.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here the code I've just used to add custom sub option page to ACF option page applied to your example. You have to declare your option page twice with the same identifier (in ACF and with the normal way). So, it's a little tricky, but it works:

```
function add_acf_option_page() {
    if( function_exists('acf_add_options_page') ) {
        acf_add_options_page(array(
            'page_title'    => 'Theme General Settings',
            'menu_title'    => 'Theme Settings',
            'menu_slug'     => 'theme-general-settings',
            'capability'    => 'manage_options',
            'redirect'      => false
        ));
        acf_add_options_sub_page( array(
            'page_title'  => __( 'Books Shortcode Reference', 'textdomain' ),
            'menu_title'  => __( 'Shortcode Reference', 'textdomain' ),
            'parent_slug' => 'theme-general-settings',
            'capability' => 'manage_options',
            'menu_slug'   => 'books-ref-page',
        ) );
    }
}
add_action('acf/init', 'add_acf_option_page' );

function add_custom_option_page() {
    add_submenu_page( 
        null, 
        __( 'Books Shortcode Reference', 'textdomain' ), 
        __( 'Shortcode Reference', 'textdomain' ),
        'manage_options', 
        'books-ref-page', 
        'books_ref_page_callback'
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'add_custom_option_page');

function books_ref_page_callback() {
     ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h1><?php _e( 'Books Shortcode Reference', 'textdomain' ); ?></h1>
        <p><?php _e( 'Helpful stuff here', 'textdomain' ); ?></p>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You also don't have to do both a parent and a child. I wanted a page to be a sub of another, existing, item (custom post type) so I simply did the below.

To set your page as a child/sub of an existing item (doesn't even need to be an options page, again mine is a CPT) just specify the parent_slug in the acf_add_options_page

```
'parent_slug'   => 'edit.php?post_type=orders',
```

Here is all the code

```
if( function_exists('acf_add_options_page') ) {
    acf_add_options_page(array(
        'page_title'    => 'ACF Options',
        'menu_title'    => 'ACF Options',
        'parent_slug'   => 'edit.php?post_type=orders',
        'menu_slug'     => 'books-ref-page',
        'redirect'      => false
    ));
}
function add_custom_option_page() {
    add_submenu_page(
        'edit.php?post_type=orders',
        __( 'Books Shortcode Reference', 'textdomain' ), 
        __( 'Shortcode Reference', 'textdomain' ),
        'manage_options', 
        'books-ref-page', 
        'books_ref_page_callback'
    );
} add_action('admin_menu', 'add_custom_option_page');
function books_ref_page_callback() {
     ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h1><?php _e( 'Books Shortcode Reference', 'textdomain' ); ?></h1>
        <p><?php _e( 'Helpful stuff here', 'textdomain' ); ?></p>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I don't like with @Luc's answer is that when you click on the submenu link, the "main" link in the admin menu doesn't get the `.wp-menu-open` class that would normally open the menu for every sublink.

Here is another option to get it done.

```
<?php

add_action( 'acf/init',
    /**
     * Register the option page as a `root` admin menu item
     */
    function () {
        // create a root menu
        add_menu_page( 'Foo', 'Foo', 'edit_posts', 'foo', null, 'dashicons-images-alt' );
        
        // use the same slug for the options page
        acf_add_options_page( [
            'title'       => 'Foo',
            'menu_slug'   => 'foo',
            'parent_slug' => 'foo',
        ] );
    }
);

add_action( 'admin_menu',
    /**
     * Register the custom submenu with its callback function.
     * The hook priority must be over 99 which is used by ACF to register the admin menu.
     */
    function () {
        // remove the subpage created by ACF from the menu
        remove_submenu_page( 'foo', 'foo' );
        
        // manually add the submenu page linked to ACF options page
        add_submenu_page( 'foo', 'Foo', 'Foo', 'edit_posts', 'foo', null );
        
        // add the custom subpage with callback
        add_submenu_page( 'foo', 'Bar sub menu', 'Bar sub menu', 'edit_posts', 'foo-import', 'foo_bar_callback' );
    }, 100
);

function foo_bar_callback() {
    ?>
    <h1>Bar sub menu</h1>
    <div>Some stuff</div>
    <?php
}
```